# finding the average of an array with a for loop in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to find the average value of the array, I'm stumped on how to add the array values together, I have the for loop condition set up ( for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

but how do I add the array values together ??

instructions:

// * PART 1
// * Return the average value for the given array of numbers.
// * Example: getAverage([22, 45, 4, 65]) => 34
// * */

where I'm at:

```
    function getAverage(array) {    
      for ( let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
      let total =              <-How do I add them together to get the total?
       return total / array.length
     } 

    }

    console.log(getAverage([20, 22, 24, 26]));
```

Comment: Tangential: based on your asked questions I’d recommend a tutorial, and taking a step back and try to think through what you’re learning. It feels like you’re rushing and not really grokking what you’re typing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `+` operator.
Create a variable outside of your loop, set it to `0`, and add the value each time.

```js
function getAverage(array) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array[i];
    }
    return total / array.length;
}
```

Comment: this was perfect! thank you i didn't think about setting a variable outside the loop to add the values too! thank you so much this opens up alot of things for me, your awsome !

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect opportunity to use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
function getAverage(array) {
    return array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item, 0) / array.length;
}
```

Comment: I havent gotten to the point in my program where I've learned about all the properties that go along with arrays, so I'm limitied on how I'm allowed to solve the problem, otherwise this would have been awsome! thank you, and its definetly something that works!